# Moving the comma from beginning to middle of a string

Tags: bash, printf

For some of you this may be easy, but I am really getting mad this time!

I use `ssconvert` to export data from a xlsx file, I need to format the text to match the real values used in the excel file. I can not use the `format=raw` (for those who know what I'm talking about).

**The question is**:
One of these values is a column of *percentage numbers* shown as **00,00%**.
At the time I export a field of this column, the value changes to **0,0000**.

**I'd need to "convert" it back to 00,00%**.

---

**What I've done**:
One of the real values, is:  **63,73%**.

I know I can format the output with `printf`, using the [manual](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) I was able to convert this number into this form:

```
printf "%'d\n" $((0,6373*10))
63,730
```

**Which is wrong for 2 reasons**:

**1**. To move a comma of 2 digits, one would multiply the value for 100 -> **0.6373*100 = 63,73**. But it seems this does not apply on bash where I get this error:

```
perc=$(echo $line | awk -F';' '{print $3}') # output is 0,6373 in a while loop
perc=$(($perc*100))
./process_ssconvert.sh: line 24: *100: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "*100")
```

**2**. Using printf and multiply the value as shown before, the output is 63,730. I need to remove the last digit (and I believe it is the wrong procedure anyway).

### How do I convert the value 0,0000 into 00,00% ?

Thanks everybody

**EDIT**:
As requested, I clarify it better.

There are 366 values for the percentage column (one for each day of the year with leap year). 
The excel contains lots of columns, therefore it contains several values.

From the column of percentage, the format I export is 0,0000. ssconvert, without the "raw" format, exports these values in this format. I can not use the "raw" format.

I find myself having a huge text file with some columns to be edited. One is this percentage column.

```
cat ${CSV} | while read line
do 
perc=$(echo $line | awk -F';' '{print $3}') #suppose the value is 0,6373
perc=$(($perc*100)) # here i should convert to 63,73%
echo "$perc" >> ${CSV_FINAL} # and this file will have all the fields correct
done
```

A snippet of the code using the percentage column only (I can not write all of them, would be too much).

**I need to "printf" $perc using the 00,00% format (percentage sign too).**

**RE-EDIT**:

```
Part of the excel:
col0        col1        col2    col3
01.01.2017  444,3968    63,73%  1165,5614
02.01.2017  458,1546    67,16%  1452,5821
03.01.2017  820,2238    42,20%  1365,5321
04.01.2017  365,9752    68,68%  1055,8002

Part of the csv:
2017/01/01;444,3968;0,6373;1165,5614
2017/01/02;458,1546;0,6716;1452,5821
2017/01/03;820,2238;0,4220;1365,5321
2017/01/04;365,9752;0,6868;1055,8002

Expected ${CSV_FINAL} output:
1483228800;444,3968;63,73%;1165,5614
1483315200;458,1546;67,16%;1452,5821
1483401600;820,2238;42,20%;1365,5321
1483488000;365,9752;68,68%;1055,8002

col0 -> epoch
col1 -> data
col2 -> percentage
col3 -> data
colN -> many more
```

Comment: Sounds like you just need to use `printf "%.2f"` or something similar but it would be helpful if you made it clear exactly what your input and the desired output is. Does your input use commas as the decimal separator? Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: @TomFenech Hi! I edited as you requested. I hope it is clear now. I'm trying your solution in the meantime

Comment: A few lines from your CSV file and the expected contents of the output file would be ideal.

Comment: @TomFenech `printf '%05.2f%%'` would pad the front as well.

Comment: @TomFenech I'm trying running it from shell: `user@local:~$ printf "%05.2f\n" $((0,6373))`  and output is **6373.00** am I missing something?

Comment: Yeah, you're evaluating the expression `0, 6373` in an arithmetic context, which evalutes `0`, discards it and then evalutes `6373`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you would like to convert the string `"0,0000"` to `"00,00%"`, and presumably you would like to convert `"1,0000"` to `"100,00%"`.

It looks as if the comma in the input is meaningless - just a readability helper for Chinese readers (most of the world groups by the 1000, but China groups by 10000). So remove it so you have a clean number:

```
  input="0,0000"
  clean_input=$(echo $input | sed 's/,//')
```

This step is important - Bash (and most programming languages) does not interpret `1,000` as one thousand. It sees two numbers (`1` and `000`) separated by a comma. Hence `$((0,6373*10))` is not doing what you think: The number before the comma is evaluated then discarded so `$((9,6373*10))` also evaluates to `63730`!

To get your decimal places, divide by 100:

```
  divided=$(bc <<< "scale=2; $clean_input / 10")
```

Or perhaps more simply, use sed to add `.` before the last two chars:

```
  divided=`echo $clean_input | sed 's/\(..\)$/.\1/'
```

Now you can use `divided` in `printf`:

```
  dot_formatted=$(printf "%05.2f%%" $divided)
```

`dot_formatted` now contains `00.00%`.

Finally you can replace the `.` with a comma:

```
  comma_formatted=$(echo $dot_formatted | sed 's/\./,/')
```

You can use bash built-ins instead of `sed` if you like - they are less widely understood but slightly faster.

Comment: European countries use `,` instead of `.` in decimals.

Comment: You completely remove the meaning of the number in step one, 10,000 is not ten thousand it would be 10, and so if that number was used your solution doesn't work.

Comment: I was busy editing the post and just read this answer. I'll have a look at this even though it is not a matter of european or else, the format of the percentage in this case must be 00,00% and if this code does that I'm totally fine (:

Comment: @123 I don't think in this case the input comma is a decimal place. But you're right, I need to divide by 100. Will modify.

Comment: @Nihvel - what does the input you would expect to convert to `12.34%` look like? `12,340` or `0,1234`?

Comment: @Nihvel Do you ever have an other number than 0, because it definitely matters how it is converted because you will get different results...

Comment: @123 No, I will never have a leading 0, . First time I am trying, but it seems to be a ssconvert "problem" this to add the 0, in front of the value. I  guess it will always add it

Comment: @slim I'm trying your code, the first run the output was empty, maybe I wrote something bad? I'll check. But understood your logic! I see it to be rock solid, gonna test it more! thank you!!

Comment: @nihvel, doesn't matter the edit to your question clears up the ambiguity.

Comment: To fully answer my question to @Nihvel - the input that's expected to become `12.34%` is `0,1234`.

Comment: @slim thanks for the update! the last update helped me know the difference! Anyway: `perc=$(echo $line | awk -F';' '{print $3}')
clean_input=$(echo $perc | sed 's/,//')
divided=$(bc <<< "scale=2; $clean_input / 10")
dot_formatted=$(printf "%05.2f%%" $divided)
comma_formatted=$(echo $dot_formatted | sed s/\./,/)
echo "$comma_formatted" >> ${CSV_FINAL}`

error is: **(standard_in) 1: syntax error** I am too controlling this code and running out of the script

Comment: @slim please check this link [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/r3jqJexR) because I am still trying to solve :D but thank you!!

Comment: @Nihvel It's treating the `.` in the `sed` line as a metacharacter. Try adding single quotes `sed 's/./,/'` or avoid the problem by using `tr` -- `tr '.' ','`

Comment: @slim divided by 100 and sed 's/\./,/' did the trick! let me test it better (update the answer too) and I mark it the chosen one

Answer (score 3):

with GNU awk (due to mktime function)

```
awk -F '[;/]' '
   {
   # convert to epoch
   # mktime use time format "YYYY MM DD HH MM SS [DST]"
   t = mktime( sprintf( "20%d %d %d 00 00 00", $1, $2, $3)

   # don t forget date is splitted as field so decal of 2 in field nr
   printf( "%d;%d;%d;%2.2f%%;%f\n", t, $4, $5, 100 * $6, $7)
   }
   ' YourPart.CSV
```

assuming date is YY/MM/DD

a full version with every other field as is (and present at print)

```
awk '
   BEGIN { FS = OFS = ";" }

   {
   split( $1, temp, "/")
   t = mktime( sprintf( "20%d %d %d 00 00 00", temp[1], temp[2], temp[3])

   # work directly on field content
   $1 = t
   $4 = sprintf( "%2.2f", 100 * $4 )
   }

   # print new content
   7
   ' YourPart.CSV
```

assuming there is no string with `;` inside (need to be adapted in this case)

Comment: Hi just seen this answer. What is this going to do? because I do not need to work on the epoch because to convert date to eppoch I'm already using: `date=$(echo $line | awk -F';' '{print $1}')
epoch_date=$(date +%s -ud"$date")`

Comment: right,but if you use batch for each operation, it's very slow due to forking process. 1 awk will do all the job (it's is purpose) verry very much faster (1 fork for all). This is espacially true if you call awk inside one of your line. At least, pick the code in my code to get directly epoch_date in 1 operation

Comment: Alright I'll have a look at this too! The code is longer than this one I shared and I can not make its execution faster, but your code is for sure helpful! thank you!